# Unable to get classpath in Gradle

Tags: gradle, classpath

I need to get the classpath for our Java project in the build.gradle file.  I have seen answers saying to use `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` or `configurations.runtime.asPath` but those don't work.

When I try:

```
task fortify(type: Exec) {
    def classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Running `gradle fortify` results in `Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for task ':fortify' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.`

When I try:

```
task fortify(type: Exec) {
    def classpath = configurations.runtime.asPath
}
```

Running `gradle fortify` results in `Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.`

Answer (score 0):

So we actually have 2 build.gradle files.  One of them is at the top level of the project and contains few lines:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7.1'
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'com.mycompany.project'
version = '1.0.1'

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.sources", "ci-cd"
    }
}
```

This is the file I added the task to, which didn't work.

Then in the main project folder, there is a subdirectory that contains another `build.gradle` file, a `src` folder, and some other things.  This build.gradle file contains a lot more:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mycompany.project.api'
version = '1.0.2'
sourceCompatibility = '11.0.4'

if (project.hasProperty('buildNum')) {
    version(project.version + '.' + buildNum)
}

apply from: 'gradle/docker.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/jlink.gradle'
apply from: '../gradle/artifactory.gradle'

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/dept-group-gradle-cache'
        credentials {
            username project.artifactory_user
            password project.artifactory_apikey
        }
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.3.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:2.1.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'org.latencyutils', name: 'LatencyUtils', version: '2.0.3'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
}

bootJar.dependsOn 'cleanDocker'
copyDockerFiles.dependsOn 'bootJar'
copyDockerFiles.dependsOn 'packageJRE'
copyDockerFiles {
    from files(bootJar)
    from files(packageJRE.outputs)
    into "${project.buildDir}/docker"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "src/main"
        property "sonar.java.libraries", "/usr/java/latest/lib"
    }
}
```

I added the task without `(type: Exec)` to this build.gradle file, and `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath` successfully returned the classpath.